# How to create an online game in Unity that is played on the web?

Tags: unity-game-engine

What are some libraries which are best to use that are secure and hopefully free?

Answer (score 1):

Unity's has a player called the WebGL Player that's specifically for the web, similar to how platforms like Android and iOS have their own players:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-gettingstarted.html

You can add the WebGL player to you Unity installation through Unity Hub. For multiplayer networking, you just need to make sure you use an asset that supports the WebGL player, like Proton:

https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/getting-started/pun-intro

Answer (score -1):

You got to use webgl. It's inbuilt in browsers,  not an addon.